# How to export a saved fig file to eps using command?

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have a matlab figure s1.fig. I want to save it as a eps file. I can do this manually (file>export setup>export............). Is there any way to do this using command only without touching the file s1.fig.

Comment: there is an amazing file called `export_fig` in FEX that does the job better than Matlab for a ver <2014b (just an opinion ofc):http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of ways. One is to use [`export_fig`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig) from Matlab FEX (which is the solution I favour more). However, you can also do:

```
figure()
...
saveas(gcf,'filename.ext')
```

Using [`saveas`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/saveas.html)

In my experience, export_fig gives nicer plots, with antialiasing, and some other nice features. However, if you are using Matlab 2014b, the figure engine has changed and should give you good quality plots also.